# How to populate n cells with a VBA function output in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to generate repeatedly n random points in a given area. 
Therefore I want to create an excel function that populates n x 2 cells (x and y coordinates of n points).  n is a parameter of the function.

```
Function generateForest(number) As Variant
Dim position(1 To number, 2) As Single
For i = 1 To number
 x(i, 1) = Rnd()
 x(i, 2) = Rnd()
Next i
generateForest = positions

End Function
```

Comment: what is wrong with the code you provided? and what is your question?

Comment: `Dim position(1 To number, 2) As Single` isn't valid. You need to first `Dim` it and then `ReDim` it using `number`. Note that you can use a function that returns an array in an array formula in Excel, so that part is no problem.

Comment: Also depending on your settings `position(1 To number, 2)` will create an array with either 2 or 3 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a variable like `number` in a `Dim` statement, but you can use it with `ReDim`. The following tweak of your code works:

```
Function generateForest(number As Long) As Variant
    Randomize
    Dim i As Long
    Dim position As Variant
    ReDim position(1 To number, 1 To 2)
    For i = 1 To number
        position(i, 1) = Rnd()
        position(i, 2) = Rnd()
    Next i
    generateForest = position
End Function
```

To use, select e.g. `A1:B10` in the spreadsheet, enter the formula

```
=generateForest(10)
```

and then use `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to enter it as an array formula:

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! It allows also to put the parameter in a cell and new data is generated with the chosen dimension after each change in the cell. Exactly what I needed! Thank you!